# link_to with :method=>:delete not working in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't get my link_to helper, with :method => :delete to destroy object

My app is like this

aplication.html.erb

```
    <!--<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Taskprogect</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%= yield %>
    </body>
    </html>-->
    <h1>Application layout!</h1>
    <%= yield %>
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
      def destroy
        Task.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:success] = "Task destroyed."
        redirect_to tasks_path
      end
```

index.html.erb

```
  <%= link_to "delete", task, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
  :title => "Delete #{task.name}" %>
```

routes.rb

```
    Taskprogect::Application.routes.draw do

      resources :projects
      resources :tasks

    end
```

And link_to doesn't work, in previous app that worked, maybe I have done something bad in routes.rb?

Any ideas? Thanks!

And can it be added some confirmation, like "Are you sure?" to button_to helper?

Comment: Why is most of the layout commented out? Where is `task` defined (since it's not an instance variable)? What happens when you click the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole head of your layout template is commented out, which means that the javascript include is commented out, which means that JS that adds the magic to `:method => :delete` links is not being run.

Answer (score 1):

can you view html source in your web browser when the page actually get rendered? 
you should see references to your jQuery source files, if you are using jQuery.

```
for example:

<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/public/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, check if there exists these physical jquery source files or not? Those could have been missing. If this will be the case, just copy over those missing files to their intended locations.

hope this help.